# How to find particular User's all Report Managers Up to top Level using Azure Active Dicrecoty Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

My Requirement is Using Graph API. I need find logged in user's all the managers up to top level.

Ex:- A reports B ------ B reports C --- C reports D -- D reports E

So when A logged in . I want find all the Reporting managers of A

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [User Entity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity) in the AAD Graph API reference, you will see there are a few navigation properties available for user objects.

The ones that should interest you are:

> ***Navigation Properties***
>
> **manager** :The user or contact that is this user's manager.
>
> **directReports**: The users and
>   contacts that report to the user. (The users and contacts that have
>   their manager property set to this user.)

I don't think there is a single query you can make that will give you the tree you are looking for as a single response, but you should be able to navigate from user to user and keep going up the `manager` tree until there are none left.

Let me know if this helps you!